# Delete function does not work in table

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, radio-button, sql-delete

We are trying to delete rows from a database like this, it will not delete when checked. If a person wants to delete multiple events I would like it to be able to.

php code

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $id)
{
$result=mysqli_query($con,"delete from Sports where `id` ='$id'");
if($result)
echo "Successfully deleted";
}
```

html code

```
<td align="center"><input name="radio[]" type="radio" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$_POST['delete']` is set?  For that matter, is the form actually submitted using the `POST` method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making sure that the query is running correctly?

From [php.net/mysqli_error](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error):

```
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
}
```

Also, your missing the second `if`s opening brace and the 2 closing braces for the `foreach` and first `if`.